# How to fix Jenkins String Interpolation with downstream job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, string-interpolation

I have a parent pipeline job that takes parameters and passes them to a downstream job. I've achieves this in multiple ways with no issue however I keep getting a string interpolation warning that I am trying to fix, but am unable to do so. Based on the documentation (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation) in most cases using single quotes should work, however this passes the literal name rather than the value (e.g if I set my variable as SECRET_PWD and call it like '${SECRET_PWD}' it shows up as ${SECRET_PWD} on the downstream job instead of the value passed to the parameter.

Here's what I've tried to so far:

**Parent Pipeline**

```
pipeline {
  agent any 
  parameters {
  password(defaultValue: "", description: 'The admin password', name: 'SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD')
  stages {
    stage("Stage1") {
      steps {
        build job: "secret_job/${env.BRANCH}", propagate: true, wait: true, parameters: [
          [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD',    value: "${params.SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD}" ]
        ]
      }
    }
```

This gives the following error in when calling the downstream job.

```
Warning: A secret was passed to "build" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD]
         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
The parameter 'SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD' did not have the type expected by secret_job » secret_branch. Converting to Password Parameter.
```

**Note:** I am aware that the StringParameterValue is the reason for the first error. I have changed this in a few different ways to solve that but i still get the interpolation issue.

The other ways I've tried are:

```
password(name: 'SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD', value: "${SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD}") = This works but still interpolation issue
```

```
password(name: 'SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD', value: "${SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD}") = This does NOT work as it passes ${SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD} as the value rather than the one entered into the parameter. HOWEVER the interpolation warning goes away
```

```
[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD',    value: '${params.SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD}' = This does NOT work as it passes ${SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD} as the value rather than the one entered into the parameter. HOWEVER the interpolation warning goes away
```

I've also used ${env.SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD} similar to ${params.SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD}

Note that I've changed my downstream job to use single quotes and i'm doing a simple sh script something like below with no interpolation errors (I have them before though).

```
stages{
  stage("test"){
    steps{
     script{
        sh '''
        echo ${SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD}
        '''
     }
   }
 }
```

How do I go about solving interpolation and still passing the password parameter down to a downstream job?

Comment: This is a warning and not an error, and you should really try to not pass secrets to downstream jobs for security reasons (which would also remove the warning).

Comment: Understandable, but I'm trying to fix the warning so that it is done in the most secure way. Are you saying that it is impossible to do this because you shouldn't be passing secrets? I can re-work this to be more secure and try some other method but not something I can do right away which is why I wanted to ensure we're atleast doing it in the most secure matter at this point

Comment: Have you tried using the `password` type instead of `string` type https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters to mitigate?

Comment: @MattSchuchard Using ```password(name: 'SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD', value: "${SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD}") = This works but still interpolation issue``` while using ```password(name: 'SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD', value: ;${SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD}') = This does NOT work as it passes ${SUPER_SECRET_ADMIN_PWD} as the value rather than the one entered into the parameter. HOWEVER the interpolation warning goes away.``` So in short i still get the passing insecure secret issue.

Comment: You should also pass it directly instead of attempting to interpolate since you are not actually interpolating it with any strings.